# Cannot refer to a class object A from the same class?

Tags: java, copy-constructor, cloneable

```
public class Car implements Cloneable{

private String name;
private int price;

Car(String name, int price)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}

//copy constructor 1

Car(Car a)
{
    price = a.price;
    name = a.name;
}

clone(Car a)
{
    Car newC = Car(Car a);
}

}
```

Car a gives me cannot find symbol. I am trying to write a class that uses a copy constructor and a clone method, but came across an error I can't solve. I've been scratching my head for 30 minutes.

Comment: what Do you want to return in `clone` method? your method syntax is incorrect too. you have not mentioned the return type in declaration of your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here: `Car newC = Car(Car a);`

That line should be: `Car newC = new Car(a);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a return type, and the new keyword.

```
public Object clone(Car a) {
   Car newC = new Car(a);
   return newC;
}
```